# Angular bad data while trying to post http

Tags: angularjs

I try to send some data (from a form) via `$http` to my backend. But I'm getting `$http:baddata` error when I try to send the data. 
The full error is "Data must be a valid JSON object" but in my opinion, it is a valid object!

> https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$http/baddata?p0=%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%0A%3Cb%3ENotice%3C%2Fb%3E:%20%20Undefined%20index:%20formData%20in%20%3Cb%3EC:%5Cxampp%5Chtdocs%5Cuno-form%5Capi%5Ccontrollers%5CFormController.php%3C%2Fb%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E26%3C%2Fb%3E%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%0A%7B%22success%22:true,%22data%22:%7B%22form%22:null%7D%7D&p1=%7B%7D

This is the code, and the `console.log()` result

```
$scope.submitForm = function(){
        console.log("submitForm");
        console.log($scope.formData, angular.toJson($scope.formData));    

        var data = {
            formData: angular.toJson($scope.formData)
        }
        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }

        $http.post('/api/save-form', data,config)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log("RESPONSE", response);
        },function(reason){
            console.log("Err");
            console.error(reason);
        })
    }
```

Console.log:

```
submitForm
home.controller.js:47 {firstName: "Test"} "{"firstName":"Test"}"
home.controller.js:63 Err
home.controller.js:64 Error: [$http:baddata] (...)
```

Model in frontend (

```
{{formData}}
```

)

```
{
  "firstName": "Test"
}
```

I have some other way's to send the data, without config, with the other $http way `($http({method: 'POST',....})` but no luck.

What I'm doing wrong here? I have created many forms and functions like this, but I never get this error...

Comment: are any of the values null?

Comment: Not when I show the model in the frontend. (added in the question)

Comment: No need to stringify the data. `$http` does that internally

Comment: Are you sure the error is not on backend's side (response)?

Comment: @MarcosBrigante yeah, you are right, placed some dummy content as response and the error is gone.. Thanks! (If you place this as the answer, then I can mark this question as solved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can also happen when there is bad data coming from your backend, check if your response is valid.